# Eclipse Modelling Framework - Package Properties are missing and package cannot be renamed

Tags: eclipse-emf

I'm following this tutorial

https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/

and getting stuck at the step "Open Show Properties View". The tutorial tells me to give the package a new model name and an URL but my Eclipse doesn't give me the option do this tasks. Does anyone know why?

[where I get stuck at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSUwc.png)

[my eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuTRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the appearance of eclipse to light mode

Comment: Does the problem reoccur if you switch back to dark mode?

Comment: Yes, the problem reoccurred after changing back to dark mode and restarting eclipse

Comment: Did you file a bug report? This would be the logical reaction.